# Probability of 4 face cards of the same rank in a 32 card game

Tags: probability

Total cards: 32. Two Players with 12 cards each. The other 8 cards are of no interest.

What's the probability of 4 face cards of the same rank (e.g. 4 Aces, or 4 Kings, or 4 Queens, or 4 10s)?

My idea is: 
$$\frac{\binom{4}{4}\binom{28}{8}}{\binom{32}{12}}$$

But in this approach it could be any 4 cards with the same rank?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the probability that a single player has 4 face cards, you just need to multiply what you have by 4 to account for the 4 different face cards.

Your computation would be correct if you were interested in the probability that a player has (for example) four aces, so to account for the other three you multiply by 4. The reason is that every value has a probability of 
$\binom{28}{8}/\binom{32}{12}$.

Comment: Three face cards of the same rank would be: $$5\times\frac{\binom{4}{3}\binom{28}{9}}{\binom{32}{12}} = 61 $$ %
Is it right that every second round (on average) I'll have 3 cards of the same face?

Comment: The probability of exactly (in contrast to at least) three cards of the same face is
$4 \frac{\binom{4}{3} \binom{28}{9}}{\binom{32}{12}} = 0.49$. So on average, you might expect to have three of the same face cards every second round.